# Spring Boot + QueryDSL: com.mysema.query package classes missing

Tags: java, maven, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to setup QueryDSL with Spring Boot and I ran into problems, when I can't compile the project correctly. I get quite a lot of errors:

```
[ERROR] /C:..../target/generated-sources/apt/**/***/domain/QFirm.java:[68,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StringPath
[ERROR] location: class **.****.domain.QFirm
```

Here is my Maven pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>**.***</groupId>
    <artifactId>******-company-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>*****-company-service</name>
    <description>*******-company-service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.RC1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultOutputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources
                    </defaultOutputDirectory>
                    <processors>
                        <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
                    </processors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

I've checked the generated classes and I see that package `com.mysema.query` is missing ('query' in red). If I change the pom maven build to use com.mysema instead of `com.mysema.querydsl` for `querydsl-apt` then the querydsl entity classes aren't generated at all.

I have read in other posts that the above solution should work, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe somebody had a similar problem and managed to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: It's a queryDsl version mismatch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

`<processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>`

With

`<processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>`

And also

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.4</version>
                </dependency>
```

With

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.3</version>
                </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for more info and I figured out I don't even need to do all of this inheritance and generation manually, since I can just extend my `*Repository` classes with `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>` which comes with Spring Data and then I will get the needed functionality.

Comment: I think you do need to run the annotation  processor to get the `Q___` classes that you can use as predicate for the predicate executor

Comment: @EpicPandForce you may be right, but it's strange that this isn't mentioned in the official Spring-Data docs. If we compare with Spring Data Elastic Search then there we needed just an `@Document` annotation on the entity class so that ES could pick it up. Maybe something similar is need in this case also.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is surprisingly nonexistent about this

Comment: are you compiling the QueryDSL entity classes also into target folders? The reason for this question is that these classes are getting deleted each time I do `mvn clean` and then all the other classes that use this class from import can't be compiled before I delete the imports and references. This seems kind of stupid.

Comment: Here is our specific example that works for us  https://github.com/balintbabics/SpringBoot-with-MySQL-Books/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Ah, and we do `Mvn clean install` to generate them.